# Resources.MergedDictionaries need to be added on every window load

Tags: c#, wpf

I have recently finished a WPF application that has multi-language support. For multi-language purposes, I created resource dictionaries for each language and used dynamic resource keys on controls like this:

```
<Label x:Name="lblUsername" {DynamicResource username}" />
```

On application startup, I ask user to select desired language from a dropdown and upon selection, I add the related dictionary to resources like this:

```
        //remove old file
        foreach (ResourceDictionary langfile in Resources.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            if (langfile.Source.ToString().Contains("lang"))
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(langfile);
                break;
            }
        }

        //add new file
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(langfilename);
```

The above code updates all controls on the window with newly selected language. But whenever I open another window using below command, the controls are again in default language (English).

```
WinSettings win = new WinSettings() { Owner = Application.Current.Windows[0] };
win.Show();
```

To get this to work, I have to again remove old lang and add new lang to the Resources.MergedDictionaries on 'Window_Loaded' event of new window.

Is there no other way by which I can set the language once and it replicates on all new windows?

Comment: Could you not create a singleton class which reads and then stores the data?

Comment: You mean keeping one resource file and editing it programmatically on language change? Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update `Resources.MergedDictionaries` in a `Window` it updates styles for that particular Window/element.

To get consistent visual appearance for the whole application, you should update `Resources.MergedDictionaries` on the `Application` object.

Sample code would look like this:

`Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(langfilename);`

Refer to this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.resources?view=netframework-4.8) page for further reading on `Resources` property on `Application` object.